# How to deal with obtrusive edits?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits, answers

### The question / answer

In February of 2020, I created and answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60456687/6509751).
As of now (April 2021), it has received 13 upvotes for the answer and 5 for the question. This makes me conclude that it is generally considered as helpful.
There have also been no alternative answers or comments in this time.

### The first edits

Suddenly, a user decided to completely change both my question and answer.

- they [rephrased the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/60456687/2).
- and [reworked (deleted most of) my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/60456688/3).

#### Rollback

I did not agree with the rephrasing of the question and I really see no need for it. At the end of the day, the extent of their edit seems to be personal preference entirely (they also gave no reasons for it in the edits). For [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60456688/6509751), I actually thought that a minor part of the edit was useful.

What I did was simply rollback to my previous versions and integrate the small change that I thought was actually useful. All of this happened 3 days ago.

#### The second edits

Today, the user completely changed my question and answer **again** by rolling back to what they had edited.

To me, this is not reasonable at all. I do not even believe that I should have control over the phrasing of my question and answer as the OP, but then **neither should they**. These edits are simply obtrusive.

Before I rollback their changes again, I want to ask:

- Are they entitled to simply rephrase and completely change my question and answer to their liking?
- What is the best way for me to deal with this?

Comment: Yeah, that's not OK. It's your answer, you can present it as you like. You can (1) @-ping them to ask them to knock it off (2) if it continues, raise a custom flag and ask a mod to ask them to stop (if there are enough rollbacks, a flag will automatically be raised IIRC)

Comment: I've rolled it back to the latest revision which you wrote, and I've also @ pinged them.

Comment: I can't imagine the reasoning of a person gaining the full edit privilege and among the first things they do - they go and rewrite an answer of an active old-timer :)

Comment: And the most peculiar thing is that other edits of the user seem to be just fine.

Comment: Equally strange they got through the edit reviews

Comment: @charlietfl They have 2012 rep. Their edits weren't suggestions when they made them.  [6 of the 10 last edits they made were rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7314211/easeccy?tab=activity&sort=suggestions&page=1) before they hit 2K.

Comment: He did a similar edit to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64576652/11942268) question.

Comment: I bet 5 bucks that the one downvote in your question is from that guy.

Comment: As a side Meta effect, the user is now back to <2k rep, thus losing their edit privilege.

Comment: @Braiam The answers here are better than in the dupe target. Maybe reverse the dupe relation (even though the other question was older and this question here does not show any research effort).

Comment: @Trilarion I'm voting to reopen. The answer to the duplicate target is closely bound to the concrete case being discussed over there, which differs in important ways from what we have here.

Comment: @Trilarion nah, it's the same core issue: OP doesn't agree with edits made to their post. The answers deal with on what cases we accept edits, namely when they improve the post. There was everything: someone with editing privileges, edit war and a meta question. Yes, the other question asks for revoking someone privileges, but that's not the meat of the matter. The meat is whatever is the user allowed to do. Which is the answer to the first and second bullet points.

Comment: @Braiam As far as improving the post goes, the edit discussed at the target is a fair bit more defensible than the ones under consideration here. Besides that, there was no counter-rollback in the situation discussed at the target, and the editor there tried to settle the matter through comments before the issue reached Meta. That likely explains why the editor answer there is at +12/-4, while its counterpart here is at +1/-50. It is not entirely obvious that the target answer directly applies here, and such a case would be better made with an answer rather than through duplicate closure.

Comment: The edit doesn't look great to me on first glance, but I wanted to make another point: a post that is highly upvoted does not, and should not, make it immune to editing. I think people upvote because the material within helped them with a programming issue, and in my experience they sometimes still upvote even if there are grammatical, spelling, or formatting errors within.

Comment: Good point, @halfer. FWIW, I recently got an upvote on an accepted answer of mine that had 5 or 6 upvotes that I'd posted years ago, when I was still relatively new to the site. I was unpleasantly surprised to see that there was a mistake in that answer (which I fixed immediately, of course). I guess the OP & upvoters didn't notice the mistake either...

Comment: @halfer or worse, if there's a critical issue that makes the answer worse (like security issues).

Comment: This is why I hate the rep system, it incentivizes frivolous activity for personal gain.

Comment: @MVB76 There is no rep to be gained from edits once the editor reaches 2k rep, as was the case here. Before 2k, edits have to go through review, a process meant to catch frivolous or harmful edits.

Comment: @PM2Ring - or they actually did but fixed that in their code and decided that your answer still helped them enough to deserve an upvote (and, well, after a while you *did* fix the error).

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Those edits aren't OK.

[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/60456688/3), for instance, deletes a large amount of your answer. I'm not a SME (Subject Matter Expert) but that info hardly looks "redundant" to me. Even if it is not related strictly to the question, this a canonical, and it is meant to appeal to a wide audience. All that info was useful for people who may have wanted slightly more information.

Thus, deleting all of that is wrong.

The other edit to which you refer looks fairly useless. I just don't see the point of the rewording as it was clear beforehand anyways.

The best way to deal with this is to rollback their edits, which you did, and then @ping-them explaining why you rolled their edits back.

If they don't stop the behavior, then you should either:

1. Mod flag the post and ask the mod to tell the user off, ***or***
2. Do a few more rollbacks in both directions to raise a mod flag automatically.

I suggest number one, but, you could do either :)

Comment: *"Do a few more rollbacks in both directions to raise a mod flag automatically."* - It's just 2 rollbacks by the same user on the same post, not sure what the timeframe is, but I can confirm that even if one user performs 2 rollbacks back to back with no other user in between it'll raise a modflag

Answer (score 36):

The rolling back of the author's rollback over an editorial disagreement is unacceptable.  That's not the way we do things.

If the editor<sup>1</sup> really feels strongly about the answer being too long (or something else), the acceptable thing to do is for them to write their own answer<sup>2</sup>.

And if the editor doesn't have time to do a decent job of writing a new answer, they should just walk away.

---

<sup>1 - That is ... the person who has been trying to (in their view) improve the original author's answer.

2 - Proper attribution is required if there is significant copying of the original content into the new answer.  And the editor should be prepared to wear some downvotes if other people think the new answer is not helpful ...</sup>

Answer (score -81):

I am the editor in question.

Both the question and the answer is about exposing the existence of a simple API function which in the name, self describes itself. Why do you want to keep the content that long instead of giving out to people who just searched for that function, just what they need? I neither would argue expertise on the topic nor have time to roll it back again to try to save a few seconds of Flutter developers.

Comment: -1 for _Why do you want to keep the content that long instead of giving out to people who just searched for that function, just what they need?_, and +1 for _I neither would argue expertise on the topic nor have time to roll it back again to try to save a few seconds of Flutter developers._. Total score change: 0

Comment: The author created  a canonical Q&A and put considerable effort into it. Your first edit was probably done with good intentions. Not accepting the same author's rollback seems disrespectful though. I'm not a SME in Flutter but my bet is there are numerous recurring questions with variations that all that content helps others learn from. Did you even realize the same person wrote the question and the answer and rolled back your edits?

Comment: A much better course of action would have been to make your suggestion to the author in a comment, rather than deleting half of the answer due to a difference of opinion and then doubling down by undoing the OP's rollback.

Comment: Getting in to an edit war is not going to go your way. If you have a better question, ask it. If you have a better answer, write it. If something is problematic, flag it. Don't deface existing content.

Comment: **Adding** a tl;dr section to the top of the answer could serve both, the people who want to read more and the people that need an answer quickly.

Comment: @easeccy question-titles are generally written as a question (with a ? at the end). So your edits of the question actually goes against the norm here. See for instance point 3 here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: Bonus points for not staying silent though, it's a brave but necessary thing to step forward. I hope you will reconsider your opinion of how one should edit.

Comment: @Gimby Explaining why you took some action and doubling down on it being justified seems expected rather than brave. It would be more brave to take responsibility for doing something you shouldn't have done (in hindsight, at least) and committing to not doing it again, even if words are only words and this is motivated by the poor response more than anything else.

Comment: Why is this answer attracting delete votes? It was posted by the editor to provide an explanation for his actions, which is obviously relevant to the question.

Comment: @duplode I always wonder the same when delete votes abused as "super downvotes" are causing removal of context...

Comment: I feel bad that people are serial downvoting the editor on completely unrelated questions. If the editors actions are wrong, then so are the serial downvoters.

Comment: I've always wondered how the person being discussed always appears in the thread. Do they get an email or something?

Comment: Btw for edits that big you should probably just write a new answer

Comment: @aheze often, they are informed by a comment on the post in question. ([such as in this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60456687/how-to-dynamically-change-the-app-title-in-flutter-web#comment118635886_60456688)) more or less just a common courtesy

Comment: As a programmer, much of your task is to understand **WHY** something happens, not just getting it done no matter how. A one-liner code-only answer is nice when you already know the topic and can't remember the specifics, but it's terrible when you're trying to *learn* about the topic. Such an edit would save a few seconds to developers, but creates the potential to create buggy and unstable code that nobody manages to know why it works.

Comment: I try to save my delete votes for answers that are actively harmful, though I've been known to delete an answer that is empty of useful content when a better answer exists. Neither case fits this.

Comment: The original version of the answer already has the function name you want right at the top.  And the later code-blocks are easy to see when skimming.  I don't see your edits speeding things up for experienced devs who just needed a reminder of the exact name.  You know humans are capable of stopping reading once they found the answer they're looking for, right?  At most you could maybe add a `---` horizontal ruler to mark the end of a section to hint that it's a good place to maybe stop reading.  So I don't see how this meta answer justifies even the initial edit, let alone the edit-war.

Comment: @Alejandro - an especially funny thing is that, at the end of the day, we have a bunch of developers that wasted minutes or hours of their time because of an edit that wanted to save *seconds*. To add to your idea, I also think this is very important in our field to be able to recognize trade-offs of one's action/inaction.